# Pollyfills conflict between core-js/actual/symbol and es6-symbol/implement

Tags: javascript, polyfills

I have created a package for polyfill and load it on the client on initial bootstrap

Different polyfills are required to support two different Setup box devices

core-js/actual/symbol is required for a low end device called Youview humax and es6-symbol/implement for device called claro

Using in the following order causes things to break in one of the device dependent on es6-symbol polyfill

import "core-js/actual/symbol";
import "es6-symbol/implement";

I am relatively new to polyfills, Not able to figure out on how to resolve this

In claro if es6-symbol/implement is removed and core-js/actual/symbol is added
[image]

In youview if core-js/actual/symbol is removed and es6-symbol/implement is added
[image]

Comment: Only the appropriate polyfill should be loaded.

Comment: It seems like you are adding two different polyfills for the same feature, could you elaborate why you are trying to do this? I strongly believe that using either of them would work, but not both at the same time.

Comment: @DaveNewtonCan you please explain further on how to go about this, because i couldn't exactly pin point on which appropriate polyfill is required

Comment: @JSONDerulo If i use only the es6-symbol polyfill in one of the device called "youview" with the user agent "YouViewHTML/1.0 AppleWebKit/538.1 (Humax; DTRT2100; 84B08500; CDS/32.145.10; API/3.2.0; PS/3.8.90) (+DVR+HTML+MHEG+IPCMC+DASH+DRM)" breaks with the following error TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'new Map()[Symbol.iterator]()')

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the core-js polyfill?

Comment: @JSONDerulo If i use the core js version it results in breaking the device called Claro with just the following error TypeError: undefined is not a function, Hence it has been very hard to understand what is going wrong